# In Chrome, how can I reduce the empty space between bookmarks in the toolbar?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, favicon

I have many bookmarks in the bookmarks toolbar in Chrome, most of them without any text (i.e. only showing the favicon).  However, I find that there is too much blank space between the bookmarks/icons - it seems to be more than half of the width of the favicons themselves.  I don't like the empty space visually, and also would like to fit more into the (visible) toolbar area.

Is there a way to adjust this?

Comment: In Chrome 17 Beta, the spacing seems tight to me.

Comment: It gets even worse in Chrome 26 - they've added a bunch of whitespace between every bookmark.  Presumably this is to accommodate the touchscreen interface in Windows 8, but it's a waste of space for the rest of us.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no way to do this. Chrome is very strict about UI. You have very few options to customize UI. Anyway, you can report an issue to Google anytime

Answer (score 2):

from reading on another place:

go to the properties of your chrome shortcut and at the end of the target line add a space then: --disable-new-menu-style

example:
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-new-menu-style

Comment: I read the same in PCMag article. Using Chrome 60 x64. Didn't work for me. :(